# apacite bibliography style doesn't in Elsevier latex format?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have to change my bibliography style in an Elsevier latex format article to apacite. These packages are in the text:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
```

And:

```
\cite{Feynman1963118}

\bibliography{mcpso}
```

But I get a bunch of errors while compiling it. I tried to use apacite in a simple `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}` and it works well, but couldnt figure it out in `\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}`.

I would appreciate your helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Your code snippet is missing a `\bibliographystyle` instruction. Incidentally, since the `elsarticle` class provides the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style for authoryear-type citations, why would you not want to use it for submissions to an Elselvier-family journal?

Comment: I forgot to write that \bibliographystyle{apacite} here when asking that question.

Comment: I think @Mico's question is valid. Elsevier has a standard output that every submission should follow.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to use the Elsevier version of the APA style instead of apacite. You can download the [template with bibliography styles](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip) from [Elsevier.com/LaTeX](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions). The following will approximate apacite:

```
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
```

Comment: Does this address the OP's issues? I would have ventured to guess that the problems he/she was facing did not stem from the use of a particular bibliography style; instead, they probably arose because (a) the `elsarticle` document class automatically loads the `natbib` citation management package and (b) the author also loads the `apacite` package but without setting the `natbibapa` option. Indeed, the OP shouldn't be loading the `apacite` package to begin with.

Comment: This solution should give the desired result, but does not explain the error. Thanks for your addition!

Answer (score 0):

> I have to change my bibliography style in an Elsevier latex format article to apacite.

I suggest you (a) load the `elsarticle` class with the option `nonatbib` and (b) load the `apacite` package and `apacite` bibliography style.

```
\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
...
```